# "The requested name already exists as a different type" HTTP 409 response error

Tags: javascript, http, fiware, fiware-wirecloud

I'm trying to implement a WireCloud widget which communicates with ObjectStorage via JS *ObjectStorageAPI*. After some troubles with enabling ObjectStorageAPI i've manages to run command *os_api.listContainer()* and in response I've got 409 error, with message attached *"The requested name already exists as a different type"*. I've been trying to find bugs in my code for last few days and nothing seems to be wrong with it.
I'm trying to run widget using FiWareLab as a working environment.
Does anyone have any idea about what could be causing mentioned error?

**EDIT:**
I've managed to figure out what is causing this error. In order to list a container, cdmi request url must end with "/" character. When I use os_api.listContainer() it generates url without it. If I manually append url proper response is returned with container's contents.

First idea of fixing it - to append "/" to container's name - doesn't work. "/" character is replaced by escape sequence "%2F". Not sure if there's a way around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This clearly is a bug in the Object Storage API provided by WireCloud. Please, send an email to fiware-tech-help@lists.fi-ware.org for creating a ticket in the [FIWARE's help desk](https://jira.fiware.org/browse/HELP) tracker.

I'm not able to provide you a temporal workaround, sorry, but we are working on fixing it and with a bit of luck it will be fixed soon.

> **Update:** The bug was fixed on the source code of WireCloud, and the FIWARE Lab's Mashup portal has been updated with the fix.

Comment: No problem, i've just sent an e-mail.

Comment: We have updated the FIWARE Lab's Mashup portal fixing this and other bugs :-).